# Textfields escape out of view when keyboard is displayed

Tags: swift, xcode, keyboard

I have a view controller with custom cell counting textfields. I am using the code below for keyboard management but for the textfields in the upper half of the view escape up and out of view. The keyboard shifts the view upwards, pushing those textfields beyond the top margins of the view.

I am using the following code for keyboard management:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillHide), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
}
```

Also the following functions:

```
@objc func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
    if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
        if self.view.frame.origin.y == 0 {
            self.view.frame.origin.y -= keyboardSize.height
        }
    }
}

@objc func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {
    if self.view.frame.origin.y != 0 {
        self.view.frame.origin.y = 0
    }
}
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

plz use pod 'IQKeyboardManagerSwift'  and just paste the code in appdelegate

```
import IQKeyboardManagerSwift

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        
        IQKeyboardManager.shared.enable = true
return true
}
```